# Limiting AJAX results, and getting different outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have recently started to use AJAX with JQuery. I now know how to limit results in AJAX GET requests. However, I have no idea how to make a client-side button to load more requests. Say I have 100 people on the JSON file and i want to load 3 at the time. If the button is pressed, the next three load and the last three disappear.

I used this to limit:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/people",
   data: {limit: 3, order: 'desc'}, 
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
      // Do some awesome stuff.
   }
});
```

Other than limiting results, I really have no idea how to load more results.

Comment: Have you attempted something? Could you at least demonstrate your efforts in research and attempts? You could load more results in 100 different ways.

Comment: I really haven't I have no idea how to word this correctly for google to hand me results. Could you please point me in some direction?. I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Search for JQuery Ajax Pagination. Should steer you in the right direction.

Comment: What is your server language ? PHP or Java

Comment: Actually, I'm simply testing the site locally with a JSON file @hs-dev2MR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to determine the manner in which you can execute your ajax request such as using a button that will load more data.

Firstly, you've mentioned you can successfully return the limited data by passing parameters to your ajax request, that's great.

You can wrap your ajax request in a function that will allow you to pass parameters such as limit and order direction. Now, I won't go all out here since there's very little information to work with. But to create a button that you can click that will load more data is something that can be demonstrated here.

Here's your AJAX request. We can wrap it in a function that accepts parameters. For example, limit defaults to 3, order defaults to "desc". The possibilities here are endless. You'll obviously want offsets and such but that you can work with as you go along. The purpose of this is only to demonstrate how you could create a button to fetch more data.

> jQuery has a shorthand method called [`$.getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) which will load JSON-encoded data using a GET HTTP request.

So here's the function which we can later call from the click of a button.

```
function fetchPeople(limit = 3, order = "desc") {
  $.getJSON(
    "/people",
    {
      limit: limit,
      order: order
    },
    function (data) {
      // Do something with your data
    }
  );
}
```

The button may be something like this.

```
<button type="button" id="loadMore">Load more</button>
```

In jQuery you can bind event listeners that will trigger, e.g. on click, and this listener will trigger your function that will go off to fetch whatever it is you've configured in the wrapper function.

```
$("#loadMore").on("click", function () {
  fetchPeople();
});
```

There are a plethora of plugins for jQuery and code examples across StackOverflow and the WWW in general.

But I'm hoping this steers you in the right direction.